# Symfony on webhosting is throwing Unable to parse XML file error. How can I resolve it?

Tags: php, xml, symfony, hosting

I made web application using symfony framework. When I run this app on my computer, it runs without a problem. But when I upload it to webhosting, this error is thrown: **Unable to parse file "/3w/users/f/foer.wz.cz/web/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/dbal.xml": The XML file "/3w/users/f/foer.wz.cz/web/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/dbal.xml" is not valid.**

This error was thrown by different bundles as well, that I removed because they were only for development. But Doctrine bundle is not. I have no idea what could be the problem.
I also tried to delete cache files, but not with **php bin/console cache:clear** because I dont have access to the console.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have an appropriate PHP version on the host and perhaps double check that the xml extension is installed.  Though I suspect that if either was the problem then you would have gotten different errors.

Comment: If you're uploading files with FTP make sure that you're uploading in _binary_ mode, never ASCII.

Comment: Yes, I am uploading with FTP client (FileZilla), transfer mode was set to auto. I set it to binary but no difference. Error is still being thrown. On server is php version 8.2 (at least, thats what is being shown) and on my local pc 8.2.9 could it be problem?

Comment: The error message is surprisingly specific. I presume you have verified that the file exists and it's valid XML?

Comment: One online validator returns this: Failed to read schema document 'http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

The link is in a attribute  xmlns of container in the xml file. When I navigate to this link i get page not found. I dont know how to fix this when it is official link of symfony. I wonder why it works on my computer.

Comment: Here is container tag: <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"> when I swap those two links in **xsi:chemaLocation**, online validator sucessfully validates it. But on webhosting error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my error by changing code on line 459

from: **$dom = XmlUtils::loadFile($file, $this->validateSchema(...));**

to: **$dom = XmlUtils::loadFile($file, null);**

in file **/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php**.

I hope it doesn't ruin anything.

Comment: Im facing exactly the same issue on Docker Container builds. You are not suppose to edit the vendor directory files like that, this should be considered temporary workaround but should not be a permanent solution for live environments. did you make any finding with this issue ??

Comment: Well I know I shoudn't edit vendor files, but I couldn't find any other solution for this issue and no one was able to help me solve it. So I have no other option.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and found out that it was some kind of misconfigured permissions issue on the host container. so I gave 777 permission modification and was able to resolve it. Although my guess is that /tmp directory was not properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing only the bundles you need and then upload them to the host.
If you installed them via composer and then deleted them before regenerating the autoloader it will search for them.
If you had access to the shell on the host you could try to delete the unnecessary bundles from the composer.json and write composer install.

Comment: That is the problem, I dont have an access to the shell. I copied files from my PC directly to hosting via FTP.